# Get incorrect offsetTop value in AfterViewInit

Tags: html, angular, offset, viewchild

My code:

Template

```
<main>
  <p class="head">Create</p>
  
  <div class="progress-bar-container" #progressBar>
    <app-progress-bar [parentFormGroup]="form"></app-progress-bar>
  </div>
</main>
```

Component

```
export class CreatePageComponent implements AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('progressBar') progressBarRef: ElementRef

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.progressBarRef.nativeElement.offsetTop)
  }
}
```

When I reload the current page I get the correct offsetTop value `215px` but when i redirect from any other route i get different value. When i use `setTimeout` for this `console.log` the problem goes away. Do you know solution for this issue? Because I think my solution is bad.

Comment: Did you find a solution !?